# When doing a POST request the user is no longer logged in

Tags: node.js, express

First of all I'm very new to nodejs express javascript.
I have an app in expressjs. After the loggin I set the req.session.user = user; and everything works ok because I have a method restrict() which checks for the req.session.user if set or not.

However, I need to issue system commands and configured a route to handle this(./routes/helpers.js):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function execChild(cmd, callback){
  var child = exec( cmd,
      function (error, stdout, stderr)
      {output=stdout.replace('\r\n','');
      callback(output);}
)};
```

and another method which sends the output of the command (./routes/helpers.js):

```
exports.cmd = function(req, res) {
  execChild(req.body.cmd, function(output){
    res.send(output);
  });
}
```

then I have the method which makes the request (./routes/index.js):

```
exports.cmd = function(req, res){
var request = require('request');
var response;
    request.post({
      url:     'http://localhost:3000/cmd',
      form:    { "cmd": "ls -lR / | grep node" }
    }, function(error, response, body){
      res.render('cmd', {title: 'cmd', resp: body});
    });
};
```

In app.js I have:

```
app.get('/cmd', user.restrict, routes.cmd);
app.post('/cmd', user.restrict, helpers.cmd);
```

where user.restrict is the following method:

```
exports.restrict = function(req, res, next) {
// console.log(req.session)
if (req.session.user) {
  console.log('OK user logged in')
  next();
} else {
  console.log('ERR user NOT logged in')
  res.redirect('login');
}
}
```

When I first access  /cmd in console I get (from restrict function) "OK user logged in" and immediately "ERR user NOT logged in")

Answer (score 0):

You session login works because your session is stored in a cookie, and a cookie is transmitted by the browser in its request headers.  If I'm understanding your flow here correctly, when you're `GET`ing `/cmd` which in turn `POST`s into the app itself.  That subsequent `POST` is made *from your app, and not from your browser*.  Thus, there is no session cookie being passed along from your app to itself.  You lose your logged-in state by using the request library to trigger that.

May I ask why you're having the app issue a `POST` to itself?  Is there a reason why you can't just use a form from your browser?

Comment: You are correct. The reason to make a post from the app is because I need info from system commands to populate some tables when accessing a page - no user form with submit.

Comment: You dont need to post to yourself to execute system commands - you could call `execChild` directly from your GET handler.

Comment: Bruno is right, and that's what I was getting at.  If you're concerned about a GET request modifying state, then just do it as a POST from your browser that directly calls `execChild`.  Is there some constraint why you can't do that?

Comment: I see what you mean. Will try and post a reply. Thank you.